# Project Build Error :The target environment doesn't supportdynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, build-error

In my react-js project, when I want to run the command "npm run build" then show this error :

"The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script"

Error:

```
> edu_fixup@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZhcM.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "edu_fixup",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/plots": "^1.2.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "antd": "^5.8.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.42.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "npm-check": "^6.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.4",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-topbar-progress-indicator": "^4.1.1",
    "swiper": "^10.2.0",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^7.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "defaults and supports es6-module"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@iconify/react": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Is this an issue related to babel or webpack configuration? So how to fix?

Please help me to figure out the exact reason to show this error.